# What are the risks of accepting URL param for automatic redirection?

Tags: php, xss, url-redirection

Can anybody name all the risks of the following scenario:

User visits a page, but his session is expired, so he is auto-redirected to login page with his previous page and params added as a single parameter, encoded using PHP's `urlencode()`:

```
https;//www.example.com/login.php?previous_page=%2Fdashboard.php
```

When logged in, autoredirect to:

```
https;//www.example.com/dashboard.php
```

I am currently aware of two:

1. Manipulated links that contain external domain names, for example: 
   `https://www.example.com/login.php?previous_page=http%3A%2F%2Fxss.com%2Fmalware.php`
2. Manipulated links that contain scripts, for example: `https://www.example.com/login.php?previous_page=%3Cscript%3Ealert(document.cookie)%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E`

Currently preventing these by only accepting the value of `previous_page` param if it starts with `%2F` (encoded `/`). Are there more risks to catch?

Answer (score 3):

Someone could pass a link to `//xss.com/malware.php`, by encoding it as `https://www.example.com/login.php?previous_page=%2F%2Fxss.com%2Fmalware.php`. To prevent this, you could pass the path from the site root as the parameter, so you would pass only `dashboard.php`. Then assemble the full link on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Typing `//xss.com` in browser does indeed open `http://xss.com/`. But during the actual testing the vulnerability doesn't exist. The user is redirected to `https://www.example.com//xss.com/`, which gives 404.

Comment: @Alph.Dev Interesting.  How are you doing the redirect?

Comment: Nothing special. `header('Location: '. $redirect_url);` Beforehand `$redirect_url` is decoded using `urldecode()` and checked for syntax.

Comment: @Alph.Dev In my version of Firefox, I get redirected to xss.com by a response containing `Location: //xss.com/`.  You can test this at http://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=//xss.com/

Comment: I've created a new empty page with only hardcoded `header('Location: //xss.com/');` It redirects to `https://www.example.com//xss.com/`. FF31, FF34.0a1, IE11, Chrome 36...